# cordova startup which plugins are required?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

When creating a webapp with cordova/phonegap, if I dont use any plugins,it seems

- I dont really need `cordova.js`,
- I can remove all `<uses-permission` from the `manifest.xml` (android)
- I can remove all plugins from `config.xml`

(somebody correct me if I'm wrong).

However, as soon as I include cordova.js, it seems some plugins are required unless I hack up cordova.js. Some of them use permissions.

Which plugins are required by cordova.js and which permissions do they require, iow what is the minimal set of plugins and permissions needed if you include cordova.js without editing it ?

> related question:
>   [phoneGap startup - do we need all those files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986645/phonegap-startup-do-we-need-all-those-files)

Comment: funny - i just earned the crickets badge with this question. nobody there ?